# How to stop image "Save as" in tcpdf?

Tags: php, image, save, tcpdf

I want to stop the user to save images from my pdf generated using tcpdf, is there a way I can do it?

Comment: Don't forget that even if you can block the saving with a pdf protection, there will be always a way to do it : using screenshots.

Comment: Screenshots is OK, like I m using some advertisement with the main content on the pdf.
But when a user saves the image, I lose the impressions and clicks(if any).. :(